# Read properties from anonymous object

Tags: c#, anonymous-types

I am generating a `OkObjectResult` that has anonymous properties:

[image]

When i receive data i can see the properties in the debugger / quickwatch:

[image]

[image]

I am unable to get the property names out of my anonymous object.

Is there a "simple" way?

The solution i found was to search for my desired properties via reflection. Is this the way to to it?

Edit: Even whey using `dynamic` i am not able to get the properties.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `var` use `dynamic` type for `okResult`. Thereafter, you can access your properties like: `okResult.data` and so on...

Update: As Daisy pointed out below, you will  need `InternalsVisibleTo` because the generated anonymous type is internal, and the dynamic binder checks that.

Comment: updated the question with `dynamic` - not working either. Any suggestion?

Comment: You are probably accessing the wrong property from the dynamic result object. Can you check in debugger? I'm on my phone so can't really check this properly right now

Comment: Needed to set [assembly:InternalsVisibleTo("Api.UnitTests")] in my Project. That solved it. Thanks giving me the initial hint!

Comment: Yes, you need `InternalsVisibleTo` because the generated anonymous type is internal, and the dynamic binder checks that.

Comment: @DaisyShipton may you write this as an answer?

Comment: @Daniel: I think it would probably be better if bit just included it in this answer, to be honest.